# ssh service is not getting started after upgrading debian 8 jessie to debian 9 strech

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

ssh service is not getting started after upgrading debian 8 jessie to debian 9 strech

> ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-05-28 13:36:30 UTC;
> 10min ago   Process: 2155 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
> (code=exited, status=255)   Process: 2152 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd
> -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 2155 (code=exited, status=255)
>
> May 28 13:36:29 ip-172-31-43-40 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure
> Shell server... May 28 13:36:30 ip-172-31-43-40 systemd[1]:
> ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a May 28
> 13:36:30 ip-172-31-43-40 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure
> Shell server. May 28 13:36:30 ip-172-31-43-40 systemd[1]: ssh.service:
> Unit entered failed state. May 28 13:36:30 ip-172-31-43-40 systemd[1]:
> ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Answer (score 2):

kindly check the source list, in your source list might be something that disables the SSH
kindly use the different source list